# How does Radix Sort work for 32-bit (or higher) integersorting?

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

I get the point that the 32-bit integer is broken down into 8-bit chunks. Can somebody give me a little bit more explanation on how the passes work? A simple example will help me understand it better. As an example, I have 2147507648 and 2147507672. I break them down into 8-bit chunks. 128 0 093 216 is the breakdown for 2147507672 and 128 0 093 192 is the breakdown for 2147507648.

I understand how the LSD radix sort works for radix 10. I would appreciate it if somebody could show me how the sorting works for those 32 bit integers after I get the 8-bit chunks.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The general idea behind radix sort on a group of numbers is to write the number in some number base b, then process the numbers one base-b digit at a time. If you're comfortable with base-10 radix sort, then it's not too much more work to adjust the algorithm to work in other bases.

As an example, let's suppose we want to do a base-2 (binary) radix sort. In that case, we'd write the numbers in base 2 (binary). Instead of having ten buckets, we'd have two buckets. Instead of looking at the digits of the numbers one at a time, we'd look at the bits of the numbers one at a time. Other than that, the algorithm is basically the same as in base-10.

When you break the number apart into eight-bit groups, you can think about what you're doing as writing the number in base 256. Why? Well, to reason by analogy, suppose that you take base-10 radix sort (the one you're used to) and instead of having 10 buckets, you have 100 buckets. Then, instead of processing digits one at a time, you process the digits two at a time. This still works correctly (I hope you see why!) and is not too hard to implement. This process is completely identical to using a base-100 radix sort - by grouping together adjacent base-10 digits, you form base-100 digits. Grouping digits into threes gives base-1000 radix sort, as another example. So now let's go back to binary. Each bit is a base-2 digit. A group of two bits can be thought of as a base-4 digit. A group of four bits can be thought of as a base-16 digit, and a group of eight bits therefore forms a base-256 digit.

So, to answer your question, the way to convert from base-10 radix sort radix sort on blocks of eight bits each is to think about what you're doing as base-256 radix sort, then implement the algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Before you jump into `Radix Sort`, are you thoroughly familiar with `Counting Sort` ?
If you understand `Counting Sort` then you would quite easily realize how Radix Sort works and be able to implement it yourself.

Another few things you need to know are keeping track of the frequency of the numbers and then calculating the cumulative frequency. The cumulative frequency decides the position of th elements in the final sorted array.

Here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mxp4JLGasE

Comment: Yes, I understood it with the help of simple examples :-). I just want to understand how the math behind it works. I just understood some of the comparison based sorting algorithms. I will try to do the implementation later.

Comment: Radix sort is, basically, counting sort applied to numbers repeatedly based on their *units,tens,hundreds* position

Comment: -1, This should be a comment. It does not contain any real information about either sort, and just an explanation link about counting, there is still a non-trivial step from counting to radix that you don't explain. It is also expected on SO to at least copy the essentials from the link into your answer, because it is not impossible that video goes down sometime in the future.

Comment: @KillianDS Can you tell me how to make the answer better ? :)